# Netsuite Saved Search does not export all results

Tags: export, netsuite, saved-searches

I've created a saved search of historical order data in Netsuite. When I run the saved search filtering it for a period of one particular month, 1259 results are returned, with orders on every day of the date range—spanning several "pages" in the saved search results.

However, if I download that to CSV, only 50 results are downloaded. I've searched far and wide for what could be restricting the download and found nothing.

I have to get this data out, and this CSV download malfunction is a major obstacle.

Any ideas on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

**Here's what I've tried and what resulted:**

I ran the saved search, and clicked the CSV download icon. I was expecting all 1259 result rows to appear in the CSV.

I've been trying this with a limited set of data to make sure it's not a time-out issue. It's not. The whole thing runs in about 15 seconds.

I've also tried creating a Persisting CSV file, and that yielded the same results. Only 50 line items were downloaded.

Comment: I seem to remember something like this in the distant past (22 years on Netsuite) Check your results tab for any limiting things. e.g. like no Max Results.  Try clicking the XLS export and seeing if that gives all the results. I that works try removing text columns that might have non Windows character set characters or try specifying UTF-8 as the character set when you open the .csv.